# Возможно ли скрыть многосимвольный код в inline кнопке телеграм бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Возможно ли скрыть код по типу `UHnUd2qun2731njkfdms7HQJN` в `inline` кнопке, чтобы на ней было написано "скопировать код", а при нажатии копировался сам код?

Answer (score 2):

как вариант:

```
def keyboard(where_call):
    value = 'YourCode!'  # функция генерации случайного кода
    if where_call == 'start':
        markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        callback_button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Показать код',
                                                             callback_data="['show', '" + value + "']")
        markup.add(callback_button)
        return markup

    elif where_call == 'hide':
        markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        callback_button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Скрыть код', callback_data='hide')
        markup.add(callback_button)
        return markup


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    img = open('files/IMG_0509.JPG', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, img, reply_markup=keyboard('start'))
    img.close()


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data.startswith("['show'"):
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, '`{}`'.format(ast.literal_eval(call.data)[1]), parse_mode='Markdown',
                         reply_markup=keyboard('hide'))

    elif call.data == 'hide':
        bot.delete_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id)
```

Таким образом при нажатии `Скрыть код` сообщение с ним будет удалено.

`Markdown` позволит копировать код на мобильных устройствах по клику на него.

Answer (score 1):

если это кнопка типа callback:
то она принимает callback_data, которая может быть только строкой, нужно просто передать ее именованным аргументом

```
#code_to_be_copied = '''строка данных с кодом''', которая приходит в функцию создания кнопки
 
def some_func(code_to_be_copied)
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    callback_button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='скопировать код', callback_data = code_to_be_copied)
    markup.add(callback_button)

    return markup
```

далее по call.data можно вернуть это значение
Например:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_listener(call):
    return call.data
```

Comment: и да, данный метод действителен для библиотеки pyTelegramBotAPI...

Comment: если вместо (code_to_be_copied) я вставляю свой код то pycharm  выдает ошибку invalid syntax.

Comment: я так понимаю мне сначала надо написать ABC = q3nu42rnur1byyr1h1u3br, а уже потом вставить это в функцию?

Comment: а откуда кнопка берет эти значения "q3nu42rnur1byyr1h1u3br" ?

Comment: функция def some_func(code_to_be_copied) ожидает на вход один атрибут code_to_be_copied, в котором хранится то самое значение, взятое от куда-либо (например  из Базы).

Comment: не плохое объяснение работы с Инлайн-кнопками https://groosha.gitbook.io/telegram-bot-lessons/chapter8

Comment: Объясню подробно. У меня в карточной игре есть колоды и на них нужно написать код для других людей, чтобы поделиться колодой генерируется код из различных букв и цифр по типу "HDfY27hew8juQ". Я хочу делать чтобы при выборе колоды открывалась функция где будет фотография колоды и под ней инлайн кнопка при нажатии на которую копируется код в буфер обмена. Но чтобы не терять красоту я хочу, чтобы вместо кода было написано "скопировать код".

Answer (score 0):

Просто так скопировать в буфер не получится, единственный способ, который я знаю это использовать parse_mode='Markdown', но как именно это реализовать к сожалению не знаю

что-то вроде:

```
...
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                 text="*bold* _italic_ `fixed width font` [copy](http://google.com).",
                 parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Есть много подобных вопросов, попробуйте поэкспериментировать с этим

Мой пример отсюда:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713920/how-to-make-that-when-you-click-on-the-text-it-was-copied-pytelegrambotapi/59714935#59714935